# Track child records versioning and query performance

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2014, performance, query-performance

We have a database with versioned data and we are trying to find out a faster to query data.

There is a `Model` table and a few child tables (eg: `Template` Table) having references to `Model`. When there is a change in a Child table, it creates a new `Model` version and creates a new record in the child table.

In the following example there are 3 changes for the `First` Model ( so 3 versions). In the `Template` Table there are 4 different templates belongs to the `First` model.

**Model Table**

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| ID | Name   | VersionID |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 1  | First  | 1         |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 2  | Second | 1         |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 3  | Third  | 1         |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 1  | First  | 2         |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 1  | First  | 3         |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

When there is template change for a model, it creates a new record in the Template table just for that Template.

**Template Table**

```
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| ID | ModelID | ModelVersionID | Data |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| 1  | 1       | 1              | xxx  |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| 2  | 1       | 1              | xxx  |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| 3  | 1       | 1              | xxx  |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| 4  | 1       | 1              | xxx  |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| 5  | 2       | 1              | xxx  |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| 6  | 3       | 1              | xxx  |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| 1  | 1       | 2              | xxx  |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| 2  | 1       | 2              | xxx  |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| 6  | 1       | 2              | xxx  |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| 1  | 1       | 3              | xxx  |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
```

When I want to load the *latest* Templates for model version 3. I have to write a query to get the latest version of Template for `ModelVersionId <= 3` (I am not sure how to write that query properly in a single sql statement)

Following templates should be the result for Model version 3.

```
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| ID | ModelID | ModelVersionID | Data |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| 3  | 1       | 1              | xxx  |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| 4  | 1       | 1              | xxx  |
+----+---------+----------------+------+   
| 2  | 1       | 2              | xxx  |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| 6  | 1       | 2              | xxx  |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
| 1  | 1       | 3              | xxx  |
+----+---------+----------------+------+
```

This approach will be slow when there are 100s of versions for every `Model` and thousands of records in the `Template` table. So there is another approach we are considering.

Adding FromDateTime and ToDateTime in child tables.

**Model Table**

```
+----+--------+-----------+-----------------------|
| ID | Name   | VersionID | CreatedDateTime       |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 1  | First  | 1         |    ......             |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------------------+
| .  | .....  | ....      |    ......             |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 1  | First  | 3         |2018-04-18 15:07:28.920|
+----+--------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

**Template Table**

```
+----+---------+----------------+------+--------------+------------+
| ID | ModelID | ModelVersionID | Data | FromDateTime | ToDateTime |
+----+---------+----------------+------+--------------+------------+
| 1  | 1       | 1              | xxx  |              |            |
+----+---------+----------------+------+--------------+------------+
| .  | .....   | .....          | ...  |   ......     |   ......   |
+----+---------+----------------+------+--------------+------------+
```

ToDateTime is `NULL` for the current(latest) record.

So, if I want to load the latest templates for the latest model version. It is easy, just load the Templates for `ModelId` 1 where `ToDateTime` is `NULL`.

When I want to load templates for an old Model version. The query will be

```
FromDateTime  >= CreatedDateTime AND ToDateTime   <= CreatedDateTime
```

If we index `FromDateTime` and `ToDateTime`, above query should be much fast than the previous case. Before going ahead with that direction, I am wondering if there are other common patterns to solve this type of versioning?

Comment: It is not 100% clear. What is latest model version in Template table. I think for modelid=1,modelversionid=3 is latest version ?what is latest version for modelid=1 ? As per your output it appear that you need latest 2 record for each model and its each version ?

Comment: it is not clear that how both tables are populated ?suppose I have only record in model table of modelid=1 and version=1.Now when will template table populated and when will modelid=1 become version 2 in model table.is it that when I edit same templateid=1 then new record with version 2 will insert in both table ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh : For the "First" model, there are three versions. And correct Version:3 is the latest.

A UseCase, "First" Model has five Templates in Version:1. Those Templates are created when creating the Model. If you want to make a change to a Template or add a new Template. You need to open the latest version of the Model and edit Templates. When saving, it save a new Model Version in the "Model" table and create new Templates records for that model version.

Comment: did you use row_number to get rownum correctly ?any update.

Answer (score 1):

For your date ranges, always use the max collating value (typically 9999-12-31) for the end time to represent "current" or "until further notice".  This means that your queries for finding a record that is current at a particular point in time (including `GETDATE()`) will be consistent.

See also my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011914/how-to-represent-end-of-time-in-a-database/8027185#8027185) on Stack Overflow, with additional details and tips.